# wordpress menu display children only when on parent page

Tags: wordpress

I have the following menu structure:

```
- Page 1
-- Subpage 1 of Page 1
-- Subpage 2 of Page 1
-- Subpage 3 of Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3
- Page 4
```

Now I want to generate a menu with wp_nav_menu function which shows the parent pages by default. The subpages (children) should only be shown when you are on a page which have subpages and the subpage itself.

That means when Im on Page 1, the menu should look like the above one. The menu must also look like this when you are on Subpage 1 of Page 1 or Subpage 2 of Page 1 or Subpage 3 of Page 1.

But when Im on Page 4 (or on Page 2 or on Page 3), the menu should look like this:

```
- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3
- Page 4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Nobody has a working idea?!? The only solution Ive found is to hide the submenu via css on pages whithout children... Better would be if it would be romoved from the code...

Answer (score 0):

You should write custom WalkerMenu class:

```
class Custom_Walker_Nav_Sub_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    public $found_parents = array();
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;

        //this only works for second level sub navigations
        $parent_item_id = 0;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';


        if ( ($item->menu_item_parent==0) && (strpos($class_names, 'current-menu-parent')) ) {
            $output.= '
<li>';
        }
        // Checks if the current element is in the current selection
        if (strpos($class_names, 'current-menu-item')
            || strpos($class_names, 'current-menu-parent')
            || strpos($class_names, 'current-menu-ancestor')
            || (is_array($this->found_parents) && in_array( $item->menu_item_parent, $this->found_parents )) ) {
            // Keep track of all selected parents
            $this->found_parents[] = $item->ID;
            //check if the item_parent matches the current item_parent
            if($item->menu_item_parent!=$parent_item_id){
                $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';
                $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
                $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
                $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
                $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
                $item_output = $args->before;
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
                $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
                $item_output .= '</a>';
                $item_output .= $args->after;

                $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
            }


        }
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth) {
        // Closes only the opened li
        if ( is_array($this->found_parents) && in_array( $item->ID, $this->found_parents ) ) {
            $output .= "</li>\n";
        }
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        // If the sub-menu is empty, strip the opening tag, else closes it
        if (substr($output, -22)=="<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n") {
            $output = substr($output, 0, strlen($output)-23);
        } else {
            $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
        }
    }

}

wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'sidebar-menu', //assign nav in admin
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Sub_Menu()
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work, it shows no pages on the front page where for example all parent pages must be shown. It only shows the submenu on sub page and the one parent page which has children... It also doesnt show anything on the other pages which have no childrens...

Comment: You should modify code add if condition for parent pages.

You can use $depth variable i$depth == 0 mean first element of menu.

Comment: You can read this article for full understanding how it works 
https://www.ibenic.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-menu-walker-nav-menu-class/

Comment: Dont understand it sorry :-(